# Neo4j: making one JAR package from app with Neo4j libraries (duplication 'META-INF/...' files)

Tags: java, maven, jar, neo4j

I understand, the source of this issue. I've saw the topic [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/neo4j/rjyf09pYIaM).

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947739/spring-data-neo4j-using-the-neo4j-server-with-an-embedded-jar-packaging) is some possible solution.

But the last one doesn't work for me.

Have the problem with making one jar package (with Maven) of my app with Neo4j libraries within. When I use this jar in another project - everything works fine, but when I try  to launch web-interface - I get the above mentioned issue. My app throws Exception with next lines:

```
01:19:49.727 [main]       INFO o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@7e75bf2d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7474}
Oct 13, 2014 1:19:59 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

And the data in in web-interface doesn't displayed, as expected.

It is really important to package everything into one JAR for next app distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue. In my case in addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947739/spring-data-neo4j-using-the-neo4j-server-with-an-embedded-jar-packaging) 'shade-plugin' configuration - I add next lines. Add now everything works fine:

```
...
<configuration>
     ...
        <filters>
           <filter>
               <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                         <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                         <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                         <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
           </filter>
        </filters>
...
</configuration>
...
```

I hop this helps someone...