# Neo4j with Spring using remote Neo4j-Server

Tags: rest, neo4j

I want to build a RESTful Application with Spring using Neo4j as a Database.
What I (very simply) want to have, is an application that takes entities (like a user) via POST, persists them in a Neo4j Database and loads them on a GET.

I tried the spring tutorials (build an embedded graphdb and also accessing an external graphdb via rest) for that and it worked, but it seems that i can't use the neo4j standalone to view the database live, because it seems to be locked by my application.

It is important for me to have some kind of method to view the live database, so I'm stuck.
So basically I'm looking for a simple way to have an application writing to and reading from an external graphdb, which I can manipulate with the neo4j standalone (or some alternative program).

I' asking here, because at this point I don't even know what to goole anymore :)

Comment: there is also https://github.com/neo4j-examples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=sdn4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options: http://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j

1) with Spring Data Neo4j version 4 you can work against Neo4j server
2) with Spring Data Neo4j 3, you can move your code into a [server extension](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.4.0.RC1/reference/html/#server_extension)
3) there is also an option to start [Neo4j server with an embedded database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904931/spring-data-neo4j-using-the-server-with-an-embedded) (this should only be done during development not production)

Comment: So I understood it correctly, that the "best practice" for an enterprise application is using the remote neo4j server (so number 1))? 
Thanks to your link, I found a new git repository and will now play around with https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j which looks a lot like what i want to have.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers, I have some examples that show me the intended use of Neo4j which helps me a lot.
Basically github.com/neo4j-examples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=sdn4 was the answer to all my questions, since it provides me with a useful "look how it's done".
Thank you.